# Freedom of many choices

Tags: chess, optimization

[image]

There are 40 possible move options for both White and Black players in the starting position. The 4 knights and 16 pawns all have 2 options.

If all the pieces are still on the chessboard, how would you play both sides in order to maximize the number possible move options for black and white? Captures and castling are considered a move option in such a legal position.

Comment: How many moves into the future are you asking for? And are black and white cooperating? Is it the maximum at each move or the maximum sum after N moves?

Comment: I read this as "Find the reachable position without capturing that contains the maximum sum of moves".

Comment: no number of moves limit and all the initial pieces shall be on the board

Comment: Hmm. I don't think I get it. Couldn't both sides just bring out a knight and move them around forever, never repeating 3 positions in a row?

Comment: @Daniel I understand, but if the maximum is the sum of moves available at each move, the number of moves made is pretty relevant.

Comment: The initial position has the least no of move options available

Comment: @Jens The goal is to obtain a position which maximizes the number of moves available.

Comment: @TSLF That is not true: 1. a3 leaves white with only 19 options.

Comment: @DanielMathias i see you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most moves possible for both sides in a position where all 32 units are still on the board is **164**. This answer was stolen from @GloriaVictis's answer to [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4490/maximum-possible-movement-in-a-turn/8392#8392) CSE question.

**Nenad Petrović, The Fairy Chess Review 1946**

[image]